# How to avoid error if no datarows match the condition in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-4.0

I work to select stations according to the following conditions code

```
var NStations = stations.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(r => r.Field<double>("Distance") < SP_Radius)
                        .OrderBy(r => r.Field<double>("Distance"))
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

The problem if no data matches the first condition, I will get error stop the program.

How can I avoid this problem where no datarow is retrieved?

ERROR :

> The source contains no DataRows.

It check the first condition and one go to the second condition to order it give the above error.

Comment: stations table has 26 records include distances but when it check the first condition and get no data .it give error in second condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate your query into two parts:

```
var result = stations.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(r => r.Field<double>("Distance") < SP_Radius);

if(result.Any())
{ 
   var NStations = result.OrderBy(r => r.Field<double>("Distance"))
                         .CopyToDataTable();
}
```